# How to render Chart (from wpf toolkit) control offscreen?

Tags: c#, wpf, console, controls, render

I want to render a Chart control (from WPF toolkit http://wpf.codeplex.com) in console application (I acutally never show it to the user), but I keep on getting an empty image. If I pick some other control (e.g. TextBlock) then everything works as expected.
Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

// BEGIN

`Chart chart = new Chart { Width = 300, Height = 230 };`
// I do not add series yet, because I thought that maybe that caused problems...
`chart.Background = Brushes.Blue;`
`chart.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;`
`chart.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10);`
`chart.Title = "Test chart";`
`chart.Measure(new Size(chart.Width, chart.Height));`
`chart.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(chart.Width, chart.Height)));`

`RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)chart.Width, (int)chart.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);`
`rtb.Render(chart);`
`PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();`
`png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));`
`using (System.IO.Stream stream = System.IO.File.Create("C:\\chart.png"))`
`{`
    `png.Save(stream);`
`}`

// END

If I run this code in not Console but WPF application, where chart is a control shown on the form, everything works fine. People mention something about the animations used to draw the control on different thread. I tried putting my main thread asleep, hoping that the other then will have time to draw the graph. No luck here either...

Anyone ideas? How can I render this control offscreen?

Comment: What is the point running a WPF Component in a console application anyway ? This is not a convenient way to do things since the type of application you choose loads the corresponing reference DLLs.

Comment: The reason to do it in a console app is that I don't need a neat WPF window. I just need to generate the graph in memory and e.g. save it to a file. Of course I include all necessary DLLs, so everything compiles successfully. Any idea what the problem is in my case?

Comment: I've come across the same problem (but I use a Windows Service instead) and this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461382/wpf-instantiate-user-control-programmatically-to-render-it-as-png/1468738#1468738) helped to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution today:

1. Deactivate all animations of the chart
2. call method `UpdateLayout()` of the chart after `Measure()` and `Arrange()`

That's it!